# CSS: How to create colsgroup like semantic-ui way

Tags: javascript, css, css-frameworks, semantic-ui

> the jsbin is here: http://jsbin.com/uMEjOV/1/edit

Hi, in semantic UI, (http://semantic-ui.com) we could create:

```
<div class="ui three column grid">
    <div class="column">1</div>
    <div class="column">2</div>
    <div class="column">3</div>
</div>
```

i try to create my own without semantic-ui famework:

```
<div class="colsgroup">
    <div class="column">col 1</div>
    <div class="column">col 2</div>
    <div class="column">col 3</div>

    <!-- but i need extra class="close" to make it work -->
    <div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

I want clear model just like semantic-ui way. Yes, i want to remove `<div class="close"></div>` (the style of **.close** is `float: none; clear: both;`)

How to do it to be as clear as semantic-ui way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:after` pseudo-element instead of redundant `div.close`

*CSS:*

```
.colsgroup:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
  <div class="colsgroup" id="sample">
    <div class="column">col 1</div>
    <div class="column">col 2</div>
    <div class="column">col 3</div>
    <!-- no redundant div.close here -->
  </div>
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/uMEjOV/5/edit

CSS pseudo-elements are really useful in cases where you need to reduce amount of additional decorative/helper elements, making HTML markup lighter. You can read more about them here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after